# Let $ V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with dimension $n$. Then which of the following must be true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

let $ V$ be  a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$  with dimension n. Let  $T  :V \rightarrow V $ be  a linear  transformation  with only  $1$ as eigenvalue .then which of the following must be TRue ?

$1)$.  $T - I=0$

$2)$. $(T-I)^{n-1} =0$

$3)$.$(T-I)^n=0$

$4)$.$(T -I)^{2n} =0$

My attempts :  i take  $T  = I_{m \times n}$  where  I is Identity matrix

then  option $1)$ and option  $3)$ is Correct

now see   option $2)$ is not  coorect because put $n =1$ we get $(T-I)^{1-1}=0$, $(T-I)^{0}= 1\neq 0$

As option $4$ is also  not correct as  Put $n=1$   as $(T-I)^{2} =(T-I) (T-I)=0$, now  we claim that  either$(T-I)=0 $ or ($T-I)=0$  boths can not be $ 0$

Is my answer is correct or not ?

Pliz tell me..

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

thanks  u

Comment: You don't get it. What they mean is "what of the following is ALWAYS true?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Yes, assertion 1) holds for the identity, but it is not always true. For instance, if $f(z,w)=(z+w,w)$, then $1$ is the only eigenvaiue of $f$, but 1) doesn't hold.

Actually, 3) and 4) always hold. Since $1$ is the only eigenvaly, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $(1-\lambda)^n$. It follows from the Cayley-Hamilaton that $(T-\operatorname{Id})^n=0$. And $$(T-\operatorname{Id})^n=0\implies(T-\operatorname{Id})^{2n}=\left((T-\operatorname{Id})^n\right)^2=0.$$

Comment: can u elaborate more  @jose  sir how option 3 and 4 always  hold.,,as  im not getting

Comment: I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: thanks  u jose  sir